# BigQuery QUALITY clause available? Needing single output for nested query

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, where-clause

Is the QUALIFY clause available in BQ? I'm trying to run the below query in an attempt to pull the single most popular Route value so that I can nest it in the WHERE clause of another query:

```
WITH table AS (
    SELECT 'Point A' as Origin, 'Point B' as Destination, A as Route
    FROM UNNEST(['Highway', 'Backroad', 'Highway', 'Highway', 'Backroad']) as A
)


SELECT
    DISTINCT Route
FROM
   table
WHERE 
    Origin = 'Point A' AND
    Destination = 'Point B'
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Origin, Destination ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) = 1
```

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLp7H.png)

[What I want (most commonly used route)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrUuZ.png)

And getting this generic error:

> Error running query An internal error occurred and the request could
> not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue.
> Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should
> solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error
> continues to occur please contact support at
> https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 80038528

If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know. I need an efficient way of pulling a single row and column after evaluating the most popular value, ideally without nesting queries.

[Here is the BQ QUALIFY clause documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause)

Comment: Please include just enough code and **data samples** to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you! I added example data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Did you find that in the documentation somewhere? How did you know to add the GROUP BY? @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: I speak SQL on daily basis for last 40+ years - so that is how :o) Meantime, the main "trick" is not just in tweaking the syntax, but rather in understanding the problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Route
FROM
  table
WHERE 
  Origin = 'Point A' AND
  Destination = 'Point B'
GROUP BY 
  Origin, Destination, Route 
QUALIFY 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Origin, Destination ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) = 1
```